# Progress bar visiblity gone causing progress bar to not appear in first place

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-progressbar

I have a progress bar written in xml within initial visibilty as "gone". I want to make the progress bar "visible" when starting sharing video/data processing and make the progress bar "gone" when sharing video/data processing is complete.

I first tried to simply do

```
ProgressBar PB=(ProgressBar) activity.findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);

PB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

shareVideo(finalVideoTitle, finalVideoLink, activity);

PB.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
```

After that did not work, I tried:

```
ProgressBar PB=(ProgressBar) activity.findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);

activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                        public void run() {
                            PB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    });

shareVideo(finalVideoTitle, finalVideoLink, activity);

activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                        public void run() {
                            PB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });
```

Neither attempt worked.However I noticed that if I get rid of the code for setting visiblity to "gone", the progress bar shows up but obviously does not get dismissed.

Within shareVideo(), I have:

```
 private static void shareVideo(String videoTitle, String videoPath, MainActivity activity){
        // find the video file
        String videoPathforTrimmed = videoPath.substring(0, videoPath.length() - 4)+"Trimmed.mp4";
        String videoTitleTrimmed = videoTitle+"Trimmed";
        File file = new File(videoPathforTrimmed);
        long lengthInBytes = file.length();
        mAlertDialog.dismiss();

        if (!file.exists() || (lengthInBytes == 0)) {
            try {
                trimAndDuplicateVideo(videoPath,videoTitleTrimmed, videoPathforTrimmed, activity);
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
                return;
            }
        }


        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("file:"+videoPathforTrimmed);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }


        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        /*
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        */

        ContentResolver resolver = activity.getContentResolver();
        String[] columns = {MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID};
        String selection = MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA + "=?";
        String selectionArgs[] = { videoPathforTrimmed };

        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                columns,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null);

       if( cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            videoUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            videoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(0)));
            shareVideoIntentBestLap(videoTitleTrimmed, videoUri, activity);
        }
        else {
            videoNotRecognizedPopup(activity);
      }

    }
```

Within trimAndDuplicateVideo(), I am trimming the video using mp4parser and outputing the saved video to a new file.

This is the xml for the progress bar which is located within a Linear Layout:

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/videoTrimProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:minHeight="270dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:indeterminateTint="#1a09d6"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"/>
```

Comment: Can you post what's being done inside `dataProcessing()`?

Comment: The data processing code involves video processing using a third party library and is very long . However, what is unique is that I have Thread.sleep(ms) within it.

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

        //pd.dismiss();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

Comment: If the code inside `dataProcessing()` is running on a different thread (and not on the UI) then this is the problem. As it's not a blocking function, after starting the function, the next line: `PB.setVisiblity(View.GONE);` will be executed right away

Comment: As mentioned by @LucaNicoletti ```dataProcessing()``` method cannot be executed the way you are trying to imagine.
You should use one of the background processing APIs like Thread, AsyncTask, or Coroutines if you are interested in Kotlin, and then relay back the progress as the processing happens.

Comment: @LucaNicoletti That makes sense but I could not find a good way to make the program wait for a few seconds; I tried Thread.sleep(ms) as well as TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);

Comment: What you want is passing a `callback` into `dataProcessing` and only change the visibility of the view from that callback

Comment: I am not running the code inside dataProcessing() on a different thread, I am just calling Thread.sleep(ms) unless that is run on a different thread. @LucaNicoletti

Comment: Can you post the entire code of `dataProcessing()`?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti I updated with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an `asynctask` class and override its methods:

```
   @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        PB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

   @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    shareVideo(finalVideoTitle, finalVideoLink, activity);
    }

   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
     PB.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
    }
```